# FFMPEG: Unknown input format: 'alsa'

Tags: audio, alsa, ffmpeg

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and I keep trying to install FFMPEG, but whenever I try to record audio through my USB webcam's mic with

`sudo ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:1 -t 30 out.wav`

I get the following error:

> ffmpeg version N-86882-gc0220c7 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
>
> built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
>       configuration: 
>       libavutil      55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
>       libavcodec     57.102.100 / 57.102.100
>       libavformat    57. 76.100 / 57. 76.100
>       libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
>       libavfilter     6. 95.100 /  6. 95.100
>       libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
>       libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
>   Unknown input format: 'alsa'

From a fresh install of Raspbian, I installed ffmpeg in the instructions I found [[here]](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24201/streaming-audio-and-video-from-a-remote-raspberry-pi-to-my-computer):

> $ cd /usr/src
>   $ sudo git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git
>   $ cd ffmpeg/
>   $ sudo ./configure && sudo make && sudo make install

I also tried [these instructions](http://hannes.enjoys.it/blog/2016/03/ffmpeg-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi/):

> $ git clone --depth 1 git://git.videolan.org/x264
>   $ cd x264
>   $ ./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --enable-static --disable-opencl
>   $ make -j 4
>   $ sudo make install
>    
>   $ git clone --depth=1 git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git
>   $ cd ffmpeg
>   $ ./configure --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
>   $ make -j4
>   $ sudo make install

As well as [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=125367):

> $ wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.3.3.tar.bz2 
>   $ tar -xvf ffmpgeg-3.3.3.tar.bz2
>   $ cd ffmpeg-3.3.3
>   $ ./configure
>   $ make
>   $ sudo make install

But I always get the same error, with varying results on the version number of ffpmeg. I know the webcam's mic is working because I can record with

```
arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f cd test.wav
```

I have thought of piping arecord to ffmpeg like [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5595/42456), but I keep getting other errors and I feel this is going AROUND the problem rather than solving it.

I see that another question like this was posted [[here]](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=90152).

Other references:

- [Jeff Thompson](https://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2014/11/13/installing-ffmpeg-for-raspberry-pi/comment-page-1/)
- [FFMPEG config for streaming](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49946/best-ffmpeg-configuration-for-recording-videoaudio-with-raspberrypi-and-usb-web)
- [Setting up your auido](http://iwearshorts.com/blog/raspberry-pi-setting-up-your-audio/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Short answer

run:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

before attempting to configure and compile ffmpeg [or anything](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15018/sound-recording-program-using-nano#15021) where you need alsa support.

## Process for resolving similar build dependencies:

Returning to this build/install method:

```
$ cd /usr/src
$ sudo git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git
$ cd ffmpeg/
$ sudo ./configure && sudo make && sudo make install
```

the last line is a compaction of three steps, and the first one is significant as `configure` establishes what optional features the binary will support.

It is normal to change system libraries and configuration options and rerun `configure` many times until you are happy with its results.

The output you want is "alsa" as a supported indev (and probably outdev.)

```
./configure
  ... no alsa .. 
./configure --help
./configure --list-indevs
./configure --enable-indev=alsa --enable-outdev=alsa
  ... no alsa .. so it is not just off by default..
grep alsa configure
      alsa_asoundlib_h
      alsa
  alsa_indev_deps="alsa"
  alsa_outdev_deps="alsa"
  enabled_any alsa_indev alsa_outdev &&
      check_lib alsa alsa/asoundlib.h snd_pcm_htimestamp -lasound
```

this leads to why configure is not supporting alsa, and looking up asoundlib.h goes [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15018/sound-recording-program-using-nano#15021) though you could also query the packaging db.

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
./configure
 ... alsa! ..
./make
./ffmpeg -formats |grep alsa
 ...  DE alsa! .. (the D/E columns indicate both directions are working)
./make install
```

Comment: I am seeing what you are saying, when I run "./ffmpeg -formats |grep alsa" I see the DE alsa, but now it says "[alsa @ 0x17261e0] cannot set channel count to 2 (Invalid argument) hw:1: Input/output error" when I try to record

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to modify the command to "sudo ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1 -t 30 out.wav" Thank you!

Comment: Can only award bounty in 13 hours, but it's yours. Thanks again for a superb answer!